# google sheets app script issue with creating a new row with merged cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am missing something? I am trying to run a little script that creates a new row and merges the cells the same as the current row above, but I keep getting a new row with no merged cells.

```
function Newrows() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const activeRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(activeRow);
  const newRow = activeRow + 1;
  const newRange = sheet.getRange('A' + newRow + ':I' + newRow);
    sheet.getRange(newRow+3,1,2).mergeAcross();
    sheet.getRange(newRow+5,1,5).mergeAcross();
  newRange.setBackground('#efefef');
  newRange.activate();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

According to the official documentation, [mergeAcross()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#mergeacross):

> Merge the cells in the range across the columns of the range.

In other words, you need to apply this function to a `range` object that has **more than one column**.

In your case, your `range` objects:

```
sheet.getRange(newRow+3,1,2)
sheet.getRange(newRow+5,1,5)
```

have **one** column by default because the fourth parameter (nunber of columns) is not specified.

### **Solution:**

For example, if you change:

```
sheet.getRange(newRow+3,1,2).mergeAcross();
sheet.getRange(newRow+5,1,5).mergeAcross();
```

to:

```
sheet.getRange(newRow+3,1,1,2).mergeAcross(); // merge until column B
sheet.getRange(newRow+5,1,1,5).mergeAcross(); // merge until column E
```

you will merge the cells (horizontally) starting from row `newRow+3` in column A until column B and the cells starting from row `newRow+5` in column A until column E.

**Bonus Info:**

If you want to merge cells in multiple directions then use [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge):

```
sheet.getRange(newRow+3,1,2,2).merge();
sheet.getRange(newRow+5,1,2,5).merge();
```

If you want to merge cells vertically then use [mergeVertically()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#mergevertically) .

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.